# python: how to find documents with specific fields

Tags: python, mongodb, documents

I am using python and mongodb. I have a collection which contains 40000 documents. I have a group of coordinates and I need to find which document these coordinates belong to. Now I am doing:

```
cell_start = citymap.find({"cell_latlng":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":orig_coord}}}})
```

This method is a typical geoJSON method and it works well. Now I know some documents have such a field:

```
{'trips_dest':......}
```

The value of this field is not important so I just skip that. The thing is that, instead of looking for documents from all these 40000 documents, I can just look for documents from documents which have the field called *'trips_dest'*.

Since I know only about 40% of documents have the field *'trips_dest'* so I think this would increase the efficiency. However, I don't know how to modify my code to do that. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [$exists](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) query operator. Something like that:

```
cell_start = citymap.find({"trips_dest": {$exists: true},
                           "cell_latlng":{"$geoIntersects":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point", "coordinates":orig_coord}}}})
```

To quote the documentation:

> *Syntax:*  `{ field: { $exists: <boolean> } }`
>
> When `<boolean>` is true, `$exists` matches the documents that contain the field, **including documents where the field value is null**

If you need to reject *null* values, use:

```
 "trips_dest": {$exists: true, $ne: null}
```

As a final note, a [sparse index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-sparse/) might eventually speed up such query.